# Why method is not found?

Tags: java, inheritance

Hi I created an object but its method is not found by the compiler.
The Test class :

```
public class TestStockItemSubclasses{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    StockItem[] itemArray = new StockItem[2];
    itemArray[0] = new MouseMat("A colorful black mouse mat", 499, 10);
    itemArray[1] = new MouseMat("A really fake mouse mat", 299, 10);

    for(StockItem item : itemArray){
      testItem(item);
    }//for
  }//main

  private static void testItem(StockItem item){
    if(item instanceof TextDescriptionStockItem){
      testDescription(item);
    }//if
  }//testItem

  private static void testDescription(StockItem item){
    item.setDescription("A really fake but colorful black mouse mat");
    System.out.printf("%-99s%-2s%n", "change description of the item", "||");
    System.out.printf("%-99s%-2s%n", item, "||");
  }//
}//TestStockItem
```

This is the class which I ran and I got the following output:

```
$ javac TestStockItemSubclasses.java
TestStockItemSubclasses.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
    item.setDescription("A really fake but colorful black mouse mat");
        ^
  symbol:   method setDescription(String)
  location: variable item of type StockItem
1 error
```

Other classes:

MouseMat class:

```
public class MouseMat extends TextDescriptionStockItem{
   public MouseMat(String description, int price, int quantity){
     super(description, price, quantity);
   }//MouseMat

   @Override
   public String getStockType(){
     return "Plain blue cloth, foam backed";
   }//getStockType
}//class
```

TextDescription class:

```
public abstract class TextDescriptionStockItem extends StockItem{
  private String description;
  public TextDescriptionStockItem(String description, int price, int amount){
    super(price, amount);
    this.description = description;
  }//TestDescriptionStockItem

  @Override
  public String getDescription(){
    return description;
  }//getDescription

  public void setDescription(String description){
    this.description = description;
  }//setDescription

}//class
```

StockItem class:

```
public abstract class StockItem{
  private static int stockCodeCount = 0;
  private final int stockCode;
  private int price;
  private int quantity;

  public StockItem(int price, int quantity){
    this.price = price;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    stockCode = ++stockCodeCount;
  }//constructor


  public int getStockCode(){
    return stockCode;
  }//getStockCode

  public abstract String getStockType();

  public abstract String getDescription();

  public String toString(){
    return "SC" + getStockCode() + ": " + getStockType() + ", "
           + getDescription() + " (" + getQuanityInStock() + " @ "
           + getPriceExVat() + "p/" + getPriceIncVat() + "p)";
  }

}//class
```

Some informations:

 The MouseMat class extends TextDescription class

 The TextDescription class extends StockItem class

 The setDescription method is in TextDescription class

 The MouseMat object is assigned to StockItem object

 May I know why the setDescription method is not found? Thanks.

Comment: The `item` variable is of type `StockItem`.  The `StockItem` class has no method called `setDescription`.  Perhaps your `testDescription` method meant to accept a parameter of type `TextDescriptionStockItem` instead?

Comment: @David But I thought I created a MouseMat object which contains the method?

Comment: Perhaps you did, but that's not relevant on the line of code in question.  The `item` variable on which you're calling that method is of type `StockItem`.  It could potentially be *any* type which inherits from `StockItem`, but that doesn't guarantee that any such type would have a method by that name.

Comment: Yes, the class you're calling the method on is a StockItem. It doesn't have that method in it. And it doesn't inherit it from anywhere either. Also, wow so fast people are to answer questions on here. I was going to reply and already see so many answers.

Comment: @David Oh... now I see why it does not let me compile, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check whether your `StockItem` is a `TextDescriptionStockItem`:

```
  private static void testItem(StockItem item){
    if(item instanceof TextDescriptionStockItem){
      testDescription(item);
    }//if
  }//testItem
```

But then you declare your method to generally take `StockItem`:

```
private static void testDescription(StockItem item){
```

Since this method now declares that it works for all `StockItem`s, it can not call `TextDescriptionStockItem` specific methods.

You should explicitly say that this method requires an item with descriptions:

```
private static void testDescription(TextDescriptionStockItem item){
```

and then call it accordingly by casting the item, since you've already verified that it's of the correct type:

```
  private static void testItem(StockItem item){
    if(item instanceof TextDescriptionStockItem){
      testDescription((TextDescriptionStockItem) item);
    }//if
  }//testItem
```

---

Note that using `instanceof` like this is a bit of a code smell. Chances are that since your `TestStockItemSubclasses` class appears to assume that all the items it deals with are `TextDescriptionStockItem` and not just `StockItem`, it should explicitly declare this by using `TextDescriptionStockItem` everywhere instead.

The benefit of this is that the compiler can check your objects at compile time, instead of you having to do an `instanceof` at runtime. If someone comes along and adds a non-descriptive StockItem to your array, the compiler will say that this won't work, instead of the item being silently skipped over by your current code ("guess it must be free then!", hurr hurr).

Answer (score 0):

You are calling "setDescription" on StockItem, which doesn't have this method.

You have the following options:

1. Create `setDescription` in StockItem and `@override` it in `TextDescriptionStockItem`
2. change the method `testDescription(StockItem item)` to `testDescription(TextDescriptionStockItem item)`
3. if 2 is not possible because you may have StockItems and TextDescriptionStockItems, you can `try` to cast the item to a TextDescriptionStockItem and catch a ClassCastException - so you could handle both types differently.